# Find directories with lots of files in

Tags: filesystem, inode

So a client of mine got an email from Linode today saying their server was causing Linode's backup service to blow up. Why? Too many files. I laughed and then ran:

```
# df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        2.5M  2.4M   91K   97% /
```

Crap. 2.4million inodes in use. What the hell has been going on?!

I've looked for the obvious suspects (`/var/{log,cache}` and the directory where all the sites are hosted from) but I'm not finding anything really suspicious. Somewhere on this beast I'm certain there's a directory that contains a couple of million files.

For context one my *my* busy servers uses 200k inodes and my desktop (an old install with over 4TB of used storage) is only just over a million. There is a problem.

So my question is, how do I find where the problem is? Is there a `du` for inodes?

Comment: See [Where are all my inodes being used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/347620/1254292)

Comment: run vmstat -1 100 and show us some of that. beware of large number in CS (Context switching). Sometimes a failing filesystem can loose alot of inodes to errors. Or perhaps legitimately, there are many files. This link should inform you about files and inodes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage you may need to see what is running / open with lsof command.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check `/lost+found` in case there was a disk problem and a lot of junk ended up being detected as separate files, possibly wrongly.

Check `iostat` to see if some application is still producing files like crazy.

`find / -xdev -type d -size +100k` will tell you if there's a directory that uses more than 100kB of disk space. That would be a directory that contains a lot of files, or contained a lot of files in the past. You may want to adjust the size figure.

I don't think there's a combination of options to GNU `du` to make it count 1 per directory entry. You can do this by producing the list of files with `find` and doing a little bit of counting in awk. Here is a `du` for inodes. Minimally tested, doesn't try to cope with file names containing newlines.

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" -xdev -depth | awk '{
    depth = $0; gsub(/[^\/]/, "", depth); depth = length(depth);
    if (depth < previous_depth) {
       # A non-empty directory: its predecessor was one of its files
       total[depth] += total[previous_depth];
       print total[previous_depth] + 1, $0;
       total[previous_depth] = 0;
    }
    ++total[depth];
    previous_depth = depth;
}
END { print total[0], "total"; }'
```

Usage: `du-inodes /`. Prints a list of non-empty directories with the total count of entries in them and their subdirectories recursively. Redirect the output to a file and review it at your leisure. `sort -k1nr <root.du-inodes | head` will tell you the biggest offenders.

Comment: The script give errors: `awk: line 2: find: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)
[^
awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ]
\`/tmp/tmpw99dhs': Permission denied`

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Ah, I see, I used a gawk peculiarity that doesn't work in other versions. I've added a backslash which I think is necessary as per POSIX.

Answer (score 15):

You can check with this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` DIRECTORY"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Wait a moment if you want a good top of the bushy folders..."

find "$@" -type d -print0 2>/dev/null | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
    echo -e `ls -A "$file" 2>/dev/null | wc -l` "files in:\t $file"
done | sort -nr | head | awk '{print NR".", "\t", $0}'

exit 0
```

This prints the top 10 subdirectories by file count. If you want a top x, change `head` with  `head -n x`, where `x` is a natural number bigger than 0.

For 100% sure results, run this script with root privileges:

[image: top-bushy-folders]

Comment: 2019: raised `10: read: Illegal option -d` ... scrubbed the `-d` flag from `read` hoping nothing bad will happen. Will let you know when it finishes running ...

Comment: If the file system is close to 100% full you don't want to create another temp file that makes the situation worst. That's wy I like Gille's answer better as it does not create a new file.

Answer (score 6):

Often faster than find, if your locate database is up to date:

```
# locate '' | sed 's|/[^/]*$|/|g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tee filesperdirectory.txt | tail
```

This dumps the entire locate database, strips off everything past the last '/' in the path, then the sort and "uniq -c" get you the number of files/directories per directory. "sort -n" piped to tail to get you the ten directories with the most things in them.

Comment: +1: using the locate database is a very nice idea!

Comment: When you can't use locate for whatever reason, run a `find /path/to/parent -xdev > filelist` first, then direct sed to read input from that list.

Answer (score 4):

a bit old thread but interesting so I suggest my solutions.

First uses few piped commands and it finds directories with over 1000 files inside:

```
find / -type d  |awk '{print "echo -n "$0" ---- ; ls -1 "$0" |wc -l "}'|bash |awk -F "----" '{if ($2>1000) print $1}'
```

Second is simple. It just try to find directories that have size over 4096B. Normally empty directory has 4096B on the ext4 filesystem i 6B on the xfs:

```
find / -type d -size +4096c
```

You can adjust it of course but I believe that it should work in most cases with such value.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggest:

http://www.iasptk.com/20314-ubuntu-find-large-files-fast-from-command-line

Use these searches to find the largest files on your server.

**Find files over 1GB**

> sudo find / -type f -size +1000000k -exec ls -lh {} \;

**Find files over 100MB**

> sudo find / -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \;

**Find files over 10MB**

> sudo find / -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \;

The first part is the find command using the "-size" flag to find files over different sizes measured in kilobytes.

The last bit on the end starting with "-exec" allows to specify a command we want to execute on each file we find. Here the "ls -lh" command to include all the information seeing when listing the contents of a directory. The h towards the end is especially helpful as it prints out the size of each file in a human readable format.

Comment: His problem is high inode usage, which points to many smaller files, not large ones.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when the other's failed on Android through the shell:

```
find / -type d -exec sh -c "fc=\$(find '{}' -type f | wc -l); echo -e \"\$fc\t{}\"" \; | sort -nr | head -n25
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use something like `du --inodes -d 1` to find a directory that either recursively or directly contains a lot of files.

I also like this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123052

> For the lazy of us, here is the gist of it:
>
> ```
> du --inodes -S | sort -rh | sed -n \
>     '1,50{/^.\{71\}/s/^\(.\{30\}\).*\(.\{37\}\)$/\1...\2/;p}'
> ```